# Flutter Hive, How to filter hive box to listenable

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-hive

I want to show data from hive, but i want to filter spesific box only to pass to ValueListenableBuilder, using this :

```
  // Read all note (working properly)
  static ValueListenable<Box<NoteModel>> readNote() {
    return noteBox.listenable();
  }
```

that code show all of available box, i have query the box but i don't know how to add to listenable(), heres the query :

```
var filtered =  noteBox.values.where((note) => note.isArchived == false).toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

what you should do is to listen first and then sort and filter on values listened

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Box<YOUR_BOX_MODEL>>(
valueListenable: box.listenable(),
builder: (context,value,child){
    final sortedValues = value.values.toList()..sort((firstValue,secondValue) => firstValue.compareTo(secondValue));

    final filteredValues = value.values.where(() => YOUR_CONDITION_HERE);
)
```